# setOnKeyListener onkey remove update method on keyboard, or how to consume a keystroke in android

Tags: android, keylistener

i have several textEdits that can take text from the user, however i also made a button that will be used for update of the information to the database.

how can i set this up so that the user can type in some text and only update when they press the "update" button that i made for the activity, and not when hitting "return" or "done" with the keyboard.

what i am trying to do is remove the ability to update the information by these other ways like that "next", or "return" buttons on the keyboard.  that will leave the only way to do this by using the custom made update button on the page.

one suggestion was to consume the keystokes.  by using something like a consume() method.  any ideas?

if this is not possible then i will live with it as is.

below is and example of one of the editTexts code:

```
     // get the text typed in the description and allow user to edit the text information for title
      titleText.setOnKeyListener(new EditText.OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        //  if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)){
                String titleTemp = titleText.getText().toString();
                Intent i = getIntent();
                Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
                String filename2 = extras.getString("filename");
                String selection2 = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + "='" + filename +"'";
                ContentValues newValue = new ContentValues();
                newValue.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, titleTemp);
                 getContentResolver().update(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, newValue, selection2, null);

                 Toast.makeText(Editor.this, "Updated Title to: " + titleTemp, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         return true;
            }
 return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Tbh. I thought that you had to make sure that softkeyboard "enter" button was assigned a task if it should have one... Are you sure it works "automatically" ?

Comment: I know this is not the soultion to your problem nor is related, but the if statement seems to be comented out. Should it be like that??

Comment: sorry about that.  i was not thinking when i wrote the original question.  it was a simple comment out the intent and it worked fine.  i thought i had a problem to deal with when there was no problem.

Comment: after the adjustment it removes the update function from the soft keyboard enter button, just as i wanted.  and the only way to update is to hit the updateIT button as designed.

Answer (score 0):

found out that it this worked without error exactly as needed.  there really was not much needed to fix this vary simple problem.  almost did not need to post the original question.

```
// get the text typed in the description and allow user to edit the text information for title
       titleText.setOnKeyListener(new EditText.OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)){
                    String titleTemp = titleText.getText().toString();
                //  Intent i = getIntent();
                //    Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
                //    String filename2 = extras.getString("filename");
                //    String selection2 = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + "='" + filename +"'";
                //  ContentValues newValue = new ContentValues();
                //    newValue.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, titleTemp);
                //     getContentResolver().update(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, newValue, selection2, null);

            //       Toast.makeText(Editor.this, "Updated Title to: " + titleTemp, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     return true;
                }
                 return false;
                }
            });
```

// added clicklistener to the update button described earlier to updeate both title and descrption edittexts

```
updateIt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String titleTemp = titleText.getText().toString();
                String commentsTemp = commentsText.getText().toString();
                Intent i = getIntent();
                Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
                String filename3 = extras.getString("filename");
                String selection3 = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + "='" + filename3 +"'";
                ContentValues newValue2 = new ContentValues();
                newValue2.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, titleTemp);
                newValue2.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, commentsTemp);
                 getContentResolver().update(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, newValue2, selection3, null);
                Toast.makeText(Editor.this, "Updated Title to: " + titleTemp, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Updated title");
                 //Toast.makeText(Editor.this, titleText.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 Toast.makeText(Editor.this, "Updated Description to: " + commentsTemp, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Updated description");

            }
        });
```